# anchor click function not working

Tags: jquery

when I click on the link, event is firing but alert() function is not working. I mean, it is not executing the function code. any help is appreciated. thanks.

```
<a id="linkSurveyId" href="/wordcloud/49" title="Melodifestivalen">Melodifestivalen </a>

   $("#linkSurveyId").click( function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert("welcome");

});
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Wva4t/ --- it does work

Comment: Make sure you are wrapping it inside DOM ready function `$(function () {... });`

Comment: Javascript wrapped in script tags, right?

Comment: Works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/TrHXf/ hope you have included the script source in your page `:))`

Comment: Are you sure your jquery library is in the proper place?  I tried your snippet in a quick jsfiddle (didn't bother to save it) and it worked fine.

Comment: Pretty sure @Vega nailed it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/L3k39/

I suspect you have something else in your code that is preventing this JS from running.  Check your error console.

Answer (score 0):

The code as such should work but there could be bunch of reason that could prevent it from working..

1. Make sure your script is enclosed inside script tag `<script> </script>`
2. Make sure there are no other errors in the console that could prevent the JS from executing.
3. Make sure jQuery library is included properly. You can download and include or just link it from http://code.jquery.com/
4. Make sure the code is wrapped inside DOM ready function like `$(function () { });`

Try below code,

```
<script>
   $(function () {
       $("#linkSurveyId").click( function (e) {
         e.preventDefault();
         alert("welcome");
       });
   });
</script>
```